# Intents not defined

Tags: python, nextcord

I used a code from a video to add slash commands to a discord bot through nextcord but I keep running into this issue where intents isn't defined.

```
from nextcord import Interaction, SlashOption, ChannelType
from nextcord.abc import GuildChannel
from nextcord.ext import commands
import nextcord

client = nextcord.Client(intents=intents)
token = 'hidden'
bot = commands.Bot()

testingServerID = 1047152916869427271

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is up and ready!")

@client.slash_command(guild_ids=[testingServerID])
async def youtubeslashcommand(interaction : Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hi Youtube")

@client.slash_command(channel_ids=[testingServerID])
async def repeat(interaction : Interaction, message:str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"you said'{message}'")

bot.run(token)


This is my code
When i excecute it all I get is:

  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\discordbot\orthox.py", line 6, in <module>
    client = nextcord.Client(intents=intents)
                                     ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'intents' is not defined
```

Comment: you have not declare / created the `intents` variable anywhere in your code. Secondly remove your token as that is personal to your bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set permissions of your bot with the Intents object.

```py
intents = nextcord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, ...)
```

When creating the `Bot` object, pass the intents object as an argument:

```py
commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write in the code so:

`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=nextcord.Intents.all())`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).